# $p(x)$ Polynom with degree $k$, show each integrable function $a(x)$, the convolution $a(x) * p(x)$ is a polynom of max degree $k$

Tags: polynomials, convolution

As title says, I will try to make it more clearer here:

Let $p(x)$ be a Polynom with degree k, for example: $x^k$ ( I think ).
Show each Integrable function $a(x)$, the convolution $a(x)*p(x)$ is a polynom with most degree of $k$.

What I understand from here, I need to prove that the convolution of two Polynom with a max degree of K is max degree of K or lower.

Problem is, how do I start? I dont know how I should get on with this question  .
I cant just do convolution between two polynoms, since I dont have their functions themselves, but a parameter.
Any thing that will help me answer will be good ( How to start ).

Comment: @AnneBauval Hi thanks. The problem is they are using series for the proof. The question is if I am allowed to take series for the answer. Also I did not really manage to understand what they did :\

Comment: They used stuff I have not learned, thus it is little problematic for me to use ( the professor wont understand how I did it, and so do it, I will not understand what they did )

Comment: $a$ is *any* integrable function, not necessarily a polynomial. Prove that if $p^{(n)}=0$ then $(a\star p)^{(n)}=0$ and apply this to $n=k+1.$

Comment: Or read more carefully the proposed duplicate: it is completely elementary and does not use series. It only writes a polynomial as usual, as a (finite!) sum of monomials.

Comment: I will try what you said, Thanks!!

Comment: In fact the duplicate gave these *two* proofs.